# Restricted query problem

Tags: algorithms, searching

I am considering a problem which seems very classic but have no idea where to find the related results. Any help or comment will be appreciated.

Given a non-empty set $S$, a set $Q$ of the subsets of $S$ and a fixed unknown element $x\in S$, we can ask only one type of questions to determine $x$: is $x$ in $A$? ($A\in Q$, which is some subset of $S$).

For example, let $S=\{1,2,3\},Q=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1\}\},x=2$, then we can go as follows,

1. ask "is $x$ in $\{1,2\}$?", get answered "yes"
2. ask "is $x$ in $\{2,3\}$?", get answered "yes"

Then we know $x$ must be 2 and stop the quering process.

Now if $x\in S$ is a random variable associated with a probability function $f$ defined on $S$, what is the optimal query tree? By being optimal, I mean the query tree that has the minimal expected number of queries before determining the answer.

In fact, if $Q$ is equal to the power set of $S$, then the optimal query tree is just the [Optimal Binary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree). The tricky part is, what is the optimal search tree if the questions we can ask is limited to a certain set $Q$?

Comment: It seems related to recent work on [incorporating the possibility of query failure](https://www.cse.ust.hk/~golin/Talks/BCST_Talk.pdf) into optimal binary search tree selection.  I'm thinking that the excluded queries would have 100% chance of failure, while the $Q$ entries would have 100% chance of success.  It seems like a very inefficient way to represent your problem.  We need some conditions on $Q$ to be sure a path to determine the answer exists, or we need to incorporate impossibility of determining the answer into the "cost" model.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, after one day's research, I find that the case with uniform distribution was proven to be NP-complete by [this paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/HyafilRivest-ConstructingOptimalBinaryDecisionTreesIsNPComplete.pdf). It is indeed a classic question as I expected before.